# IIS8 migration from IIS6: web.config issue

Tags: windows, iis, web, web-config

We have a unique situation, and I can't find an answer for it. For that matter, I can't even think how to phrase the query effectively.

Our former server used IIS6. The folder structure worked like this:

ddrive

- inetpub

  - webcontent

    - site 1's content
    - site 2's content
    - ...
    - site n's content

The index.asp file that drives the websites is in the "webcontent" folder, thus all sites share a common root. This let us have one engine driving all. It worked because IIS6 stores configuration settings in the metabase (right?).

It appears (and I'm just feeling my way along, here) that configuration settings are stored in the root folder in an text file. This means that if I try to add a second website using the previous model, I get conflicts.

Two questions, then:

1. Are my assumptions about my situation correct?
2. Is there a way to use a similar setup to what I had before, or do I have to rewrite the engine? For the sites, there is no .NET. Everything is in classic ASP, migrating ever so slowly to PHP.

Comment: Are you talking about server configuration settings or websites / applications configuration being stored in the metabase ?

Comment: Btw, have you had a look a [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7-or-above) post ? I don't know if it can help you.

Comment: The Web Deployment tool would migrate, alright, but consistently created websites that would not function. I never did find out why.

Comment: The Web Deployment tool would migrate, alright, but consistently created websites that would not function. I never did find out why. For posterity, here's what I found: virtual folders are contained in a configuration file in %windir%/system32/inetsrv. URL Rewrite entries are contained in a .config file in the website root. I ended up moving all my core engine files to a new folder and vdir'ing them in. In all, changed a path entry in about a dozen files.